# SwiftUI LinearGradient Color Change With Animation Happens Instantly

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am trying to animate a gradient change but it keeps happening instantly rather than animating. My current code is as follows

```
struct GradientView: View {
    
@State var currentTopColor = Color.white

var body: some View {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [currentTopColor, .white]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                currentTopColor = [Color.blue, Color.pink, Color.red].randomElement()!
            }
        }
}
```

}

[image]

I have also tried using the `.animation` modifier but the effect is the same. When I tap the background it changes instantly rather than gradually.

Can you advise why its happening instantly and how to make the gradient change be gradual with an animation?

*Update* Latest attempt to use bool for animation still causes instant color change
@State private var animate = false

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [getColor(), .white]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut.speed(1.25), value: animate)
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .onTapGesture {
        animate.toggle()
    }
}

func getColor() -> Color {
    animate ? Color.red : Color.blue
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting a `Color`, you should set a `Bool` and then derive the `Color`s from that `Bool` state.

Comment: Can you clarify? Im not clear what you mean by derive colors from a bool state

Comment: `pressed ? Color.white : Color.green`

Comment: I changed the code and the transition still happens instantly

```
            .onTapGesture {
                myBool = !myBool
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 10)) {
                    // I also put the bool change here
                    currentTopColor = myBool ? Color.red : Color.blue
                }
            }
```

Comment: Looks like I also needed to add `.animation(Animation.easeInOut.speed(0.25), value: animate)`

Comment: Correction, the animation only worked when I used it with a color instead of gradient. Ive updated my code with the latest (it still hard transitions)

Comment: Animating between two different `Gradient`s is not supported out of the box (like stop points), but it is definitely achievable by utilizing `AnimatableModifier`. It is quite involving, so instead of compiling an answer I can point you to [this article](https://www.appcoda.com/animate-gradient-swiftui/) which discusses all options.

Comment: Yes I was also looking at that

Comment: The [iOS & iPadOS 17 Beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-17-release-notes) state that "Changing from one Gradient value to another will now animate, but only once apps are rebuilt against the new SDK. (107408691)".

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that a switch of `ShapeStyle` is not animatable, I couldn't get it to work either. As a workaround, you can use a transition between views in a `ZStack`:

```swift
struct GradientView: View {

    @State var withBlueGradient = false

    private var filledArea: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(colors: [withBlueGradient ? .blue : .red, .white]),
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            )
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if withBlueGradient {
                filledArea
            } else {
                filledArea
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                withBlueGradient.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion Ill play around with this!

Comment: Even if you are switching between lots of different colors, you still only need one ```if...else``` in the ```ZStack```. You just need to make sure that it flip-flops between views when the color changes. A container that combines a color with a counter could be used to achieve this.