# How to animate a full LazyVGrid on change of data

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I am trying to animate the below LazyVgrid from right to left on change of the content when a user taps on one of the 4 buttons but I can't get to make it work.

[LazyVGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEXQc.png)

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(vmchoices.possibleChoices, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                        Button {
                            print("Button taped")
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() +  0.05 ){
                                    vmchoices.updateCurrentQuestion()
                                    vmchoices.selectArrayOfChoices()
                                }
                            
                        } label: {
                                Text(item)
                                    .bold()
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                    .font(.title3)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                                    .background {
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .fill(.white)
                                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10)
                                    }
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
```

Basically, every time one of the buttons is taped, it updates an observed array of 4 Strings in the view model and displays them.
I have noticed that when I am not using a delay to update the view, a random animation happens from time to time (on update) on a random button. To avoid that I'd like to animate during 0.5 seconds the entire LazyVGrid from right to left on tap of a button to display the new content.

I have tried to use .animate(_:value:) and withAnimation() but without any success.
I have also been searching other topics for a few days but nothing I found helped me on this. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Edit: Adding the simplified VM function

```
    @Published var possibleChoices: [String] = []
    @Published var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0

    
    init() {

            selectArrayOfChoices()
    }

    
    func selectArrayOfChoices() {
        
        var appendedString: String = ""
        var count = 0
        
        possibleChoices = []
        possibleChoices.append(questionsToDisplay[currentQuestionIndex].nameFr)
        
        while count < 3 {
            
            appendedString = questionsToDisplay.randomElement()!.nameFr
            
            if !possibleChoices.contains(appendedString) {
                
                possibleChoices.append(appendedString)
                count += 1
                
            } else {}
            
        }
        possibleChoices.shuffle()
    }
    
    func updateCurrentQuestion() {
        
        currentQuestionIndex += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't see how this is expected to work.  Every button is calling the same method `vmchoices.updateCurrentQuestion()` without providing any indication of which button initiated the action.  It might help if you added the key elements of the VM.

Comment: @flanker I updated the post to provide the VM. Please note that questionsToDisplay is an array of Questions instances containing the nameFr property. I take 4 nameFr from this array to display them in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get something working from the snippets you provided. I think your main issue is probably that you are observing changes to the array  `possibleChoices`, but this only notifies listeners when it is re-assigned to an empty array. The code that re-populates and then shuffles the array will not send further updates to observers (because only the contents of the array are changing, not the array instance itself).

The code you provided was missing the `columns` definition, the observed object `vmchoices` and the array `questionsToDisplay`, so there was no way to check if there were issues here too. Also, I am not completely sure how well a `LazyVGrid` will cope with changes to an array of `String` and would suggest using an array of `Identifiable` instead.

So here is something that at least updates reliably when a button is pressed. Main changes:

- `questionsToDisplay` is an array of `Identifiable` items, instead of being an array of `String`.
- The function `selectArrayOfChoices` does not update `possibleChoices` directly, instead it returns a new array which is assigned to the published array. This assignment causes observers to be notified.
- The function `selectArrayOfChoices` is private and called from `updateCurrentQuestion`.
- The function `updateCurrentQuestion` checks the array length.
- `currentQuestionIndex` is no longer published.
- The button action is no longer performed anyschronously.
- Animation is encouraged by calling `updateCurrentQuestion` using `withAnimation`.

```swift
struct VMQuestion: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let nameFr: String
}

class VMChoices: ObservableObject {

    private let questionsToDisplay: [VMQuestion] = {
        var result = [VMQuestion]()
        result.reserveCapacity(10)
        for i in 1...10 {
            result.append(VMQuestion(id: i, nameFr: "Question\(i)"))
        }
        return result
    }()

    @Published var possibleChoices = [VMQuestion]()
    private var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0

    init() {
        possibleChoices = selectArrayOfChoices()
    }

    private func selectArrayOfChoices() -> [VMQuestion] {
        var result = [VMQuestion]()
        result.reserveCapacity(4)
        result.append(questionsToDisplay[currentQuestionIndex])
        while result.count < 4 {
            if let candidateQuestion = questionsToDisplay.randomElement() {
                if !result.contains(candidateQuestion) {
                    result.append(candidateQuestion)
                }
            }
        }
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }

    func updateCurrentQuestion() {
        currentQuestionIndex += 1
        if currentQuestionIndex >= questionsToDisplay.count {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0
        }
        // Re-populate the possible choices
        possibleChoices = selectArrayOfChoices()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    private let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    @StateObject private var vmchoices = VMChoices()

    private func buttonTapped() {
        print("Button tapped")
        withAnimation {
            vmchoices.updateCurrentQuestion()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(vmchoices.possibleChoices) { item in
                Button(action: buttonTapped) {
                    Text(item.nameFr)
                        .bold()
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                        .background {
                            Color.white
                                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Your original question was asking about controlling the direction of the animation. I tried applying `.transition` with different effects to the buttons, but this didn't work consistently. My guess is that `LazyVGrid` doesn't give you much control over how the animation happens when the contents of the grid are shuffled or partially replaced.

If you really need more control over the animation then I suppose you could forcibly replace the complete grid with every re-shuffle, perhaps by using layers in a `ZStack`. My answer to [SwiftUI LinearGradient Color Change With Animation Happens Instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76098710) shows how the principle works.

Comment: Many thanks for the time you took to answer this question! As a beginner I am having a hard time figuring out these other problems.